# Executing Gradle without a settings file has been deprecated : How to write a setting file and where to save

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

hello friends i am new to android studio(ver :3.6.1) and gradle(ver:6.0.3) i have just somehow installed it (means my gradle was not installing or taking time so i manually installed files in chrome and placed it in folder and everything is okay but due to version upgrade i am facing this issue) and when i used to sync it , it shows me error that the **Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with
Gradle 7.0.Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings** then i did same build with **--warning-mode all** and i got this message --**Executing Gradle tasks as part of an undefined build has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further in
formation: https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#executing_gradle_without_a_settings_file_has_been_deprecated**
afterthat i went to the given link and then i found this 
[Have A look to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95TDE.png)
i don't know how to write the setting.gradle or setting.gradle.kts file and where to save it i once tries to save it in my gradle home folder but it gave me another error that the method i used to do so is not known i have attached my gradle project build log  screenshots 
[have a look to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJZe8.png)
thank u i hope u will help me please give me suggestions and help me to do it

Comment: please answer fast

Comment: "please answer fast" – [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/).

Answer (score 4):

No need to hurry - as long as you don't upgrade to Gradle 7.0 nothing bad will happen. And since Gradle 6.3 has been released quite recently the next release is at least 5 to 6 weeks away...

If your project is a simple project without subprojects, the `settings.gradle` file can be an empty file (though it needs to exist).

You must place it into the same directory as your `build.gradle` file.

You need more content in the `settings.gradle` file if you start creating multi-project builds. The documentation about multi-project builds is part of the gradle documentation (what a surpise!): https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/

Detailed information about the allowed settings are available at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html

Comment: can u give me a example of setting file

Comment: i am unable to find build.gradle

Comment: @RudreshRajvansh the `build.gradle` file describes how gradle should build your project and it is in the root directory of your project. If you have no `build.gradle` then you don't have a project (and therefore also no place to put the settings.gradle). In this case you should start by creating a new project (in Android Studio) and most probably creating a new project in Android Studio will also create the settings.gradle for you